# (?) SQL - interlinked joins (how to build a chain between two tables?)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, queue, inner-join, linked-tables

First of all, that's not my table. I got a project with tables like that...

### [image: two tables with multiple switches]

I need an idea to get all linked pages/questions in a queue/list in a given order.

Perfect soloution would be:

### [image]

Do you know a way, to get this in one statement (via inner joins)?
My problems are the order and also the mix between both tables, merged in one.
It's also ok, if there are 2 id fields (one for each type), so than we also can go without type (for the current element).

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: It's not clear what your question/problem is exactly, but it will be a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Sorry, it was late (1:00am), it was a long day and I was sooo tired, yesterday. 
So it seemed easier to post only a screeshot of a simple Excel table. But yeah, you're right. Better to write down source code and stuctures (texts instead of pics).

Sorry, next time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a couple of `CTE`s to first `UNION` the tables together and then follow through the list starting from the `firstPage`, using a row number to guarantee the ordering of results:

```
WITH allpq AS (
  SELECT name, 'page' AS type, next, next_type
  FROM page
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT name, 'question', next, next_type
  FROM question
),
list AS (
  SELECT type, name, next, next_type, 1 as rn
  FROM allpq
  WHERE name = 'firstPage'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.type, a.name, a.next, a.next_type, list.rn + 1
  FROM allpq a
  JOIN list ON a.name = list.next AND a.type = list.next_type
)
SELECT type, name, next, next_type
FROM list
ORDER BY rn
```

Output:

```
type        name            next            next_type
page        firstPage       secondPage      page
page        secondPage      firstQuestion   question
question    firstQuestion   secondQuestion  question
question    secondQuestion  thirdPage       page
page        thirdPage       fourthPage      page
page        fourthPage      fourthQuestion  question
question    fourthQuestion  fifthPage       page
page        fifthPage       fifthQuestion   question
question    fifthQuestion   sixthPage       page
page        sixthPage       seventhPage     page
page        seventhPage     eighthPage      page
page        eighthPage
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d681115f0bdb3f22e6b155e34c846e15)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I searched for. Oh wow... WITH and the List table with a circular join. I would never have thought of it myself.

I don't know why my workmate did it this way. Without using IDs or just in one table by helping type flags. It's a simple online poll. I'm just adding a content manager for it. So I can't change the database (without changing the original tool / code).

But thank you very much.

Comment: @Froschkoenig84 yeah, the structure definitely makes life hard! I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I use a  `union all` operator to create a combined table, and then join it on itself:

```
SELECT id, 'page' AS type, name, next, next_type
FROM   page
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'question', name, next, next_type
FROM question
```